# Is it a good practice for a module to return a JSONArray?

Tags: java, android, arrays

Before I converted my app into a library, I could get a JSONArray from the server and process everything internally, assigning values to my own POJO, which could be sorted into an ArrayList of that POJO type. Now with the new library, I want that POJO to be determined by the third-party developer for flexibility. My question is: is it good practice (regarding both security and structure standards) to return the raw JSONArray to the developer? And if not, what should I return? ArrayList? List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "one correct answer" here.

All things being equal, the more generic the interface, the better.

In other words, using an "ArrayList" (in your code implementation) and returning a "List" (as your return value) is in some ways "ideal".

But if both you (when you receive the data) and your client (who will process the data) are both using a "JSONArray" ... then why go to the extra overhead of packing and unpacking to and from an ArrayList?  In this case, simply sticking with the JSONArray would be much more efficient.

So the answer is "it depends".

Answer (score 0):

its always better to retrieve some information from user or client side for the betterment regarding durability of application. In doing so the developer will be updated with issues the application is facing